# How to read pdf form fields using Java?

Tags: java, api

I've a requirement where user are going to fill lots of fields ( text field, check box, radio button ) on pdf form and they will mail us. I need to read each fields on pdf form and insert into oracle table.

**Edit1:** I'm trying following code, It generates pdf but when I double click it says "invalid format". What's wrong ?

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class pdfGentest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document document = new Document();

        try {

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("c:\\HelloWorld.pdf"));
            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            }
        catch (DocumentException de) {
            System.err.println(de.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }       
    }
}
```

**Fixed:** Due to I've not closed the document..Adding document.close(); fixed the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IText library to do that. Link =>http://itextpdf.com/

Sadly I don't have java code example for that as I am using iTextSharp library for C#.NET buts pretty straightforward.

You might want to check itextpdf.com/book/examples.php for examples. Also check the following link for some example on reading field values,
http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Problem-Reading-Interactive-Form-Values-Acro-Fields-from-PDF-using-iText-td2171900.html

Comment: Thanks MSI, I don't see any documentation for java. They have listed only jars. Do you know if they provide documentation ?

Comment: Hey MSI, I've a question..Let's say client is creating text boxes , check box and other fields on pdf and sending us. How do we know the field name ? I assume while coding we need to know field name to get handle of those fields ?

Comment: You need to create form fields on pdf form first using Acrobat Professional or other softwares. Unless there are named fields available for the fields you want to work on I don't think its possible to read/write to pdf fields. So far you have the named fields, you can use those names to refer to the respective field items and grab their values/write to them.

Comment: Thanks MSI. Can we see a field name on pdf forms ? I got a sample form  which has field "Account Number" ..like,

Account Number: <Text box>

How do I know the textbox id/name so that I can refer in my code or iText provides some methods to find field names on the form.

Thanks for your insights .

Comment: Got it..It's beautifully mentioned in the "Manning iText in Action" book.

Comment: ah cool was going to point you to the following link (added in the answer) for some example but if you got the book already then fine:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use PDF Box api, which will support to extract the fields information more clearly.